# glDrawElements throws divide by zero error when using multiple VAO

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I'm building a game using opengl. When I call glDrawElements, a divide by zero error from ig9icd32.dll is thrown. With a little bit of research I found that it's an Intel library

Since ig9icd32.dll is an Intel driver, I tried to run the game with the dedicated GPU, but the same error occurs.

Using a single VAO and compiling without drawing the second does **not** give any errors.
I checked VAO generation and VBO bindings: they work just fine.

```
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_HighwayVAO);
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_lanesVAO);

        {
            glBindVertexArray(m_HighwayVAO);

            unsigned int vbo, ebo;
            glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
            glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

            //Vertex: x,y,z, u,v
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            glBindVertexArray(0);
        }


        {

            glBindVertexArray(m_lanesVAO);

            unsigned int buffer, index;
            glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
            glGenBuffers(1, &index);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index);

            //Vertex: x,y,z, r,g,b,
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


            glBindVertexArray(0);

        }

    }
```

this is where I initialize the VAO's.
They are on separated scopes just so I can collapse on the editor.
Without scopes the same error occurs.

m_HighwayVAO and m_lanesVAO are variables defined in a Header.They are initialised to 0.

```
void Rendr::highway(double time) {

    float factor = time / 3;
    //Vertex: x,y,z, u,v
    float data[] = {
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f + factor,
             1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f + factor,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f + factor,
             1.0f, 0.0f, 6.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f + factor
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
            0,2,3,
            3,1,0
    };

    glBindVertexArray(m_HighwayVAO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glUseProgram(m_TextureProgram);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
    //error thrown here

    glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

If you need more code, I'll be happy to add to the post.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting. Did you check your program for the presence of GL errors before the `glDrawElements` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To creates and initializes a buffer object's data store, you've to bind the proper `ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer object:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

[`glBindVertexArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexArray.xhtml) does **not** bind any buffer object to a `ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer target.

---

Note, the last buffer which is bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is `buffer`:

> ```cpp
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
> ```

This state is kept and is never changed again. So the buffer object's data store for `vbo` is never created and initialized.

This behaves different to the [index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`). The index buffer binding is stored within the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers).
Note, each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different `ARRAY_BUFFER`. This reference is stored when [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called. Then the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the attribute and the name (value) of the object is stored in the state vector of the VAO.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that VAO also stored buffer binding because I tried with the second VAO and it worked. So I have to bind GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and the VAO every time I want to change vertex data, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, now everything is fixed. I'll add an edit to the original question. Thanks Again